# How to correctly calculate the revenue of the product when the price changes?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, calculated-columns

I have two datasets:

- prices: records of product’s history price changes in Sep 2018
- sales: records of product’s sales in Sep 2018
  Use any data wrangling tools to calculcate the total revenue of each product and revenue at each price.

Thanks a lot.

Prices (sample):

| product_id | old_price | new_price | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 64 | 270000 | 239000 | 9/10/2018 4:37:00 PM |
| 3954203 | 60000 | 64000 | 9/11/2018 10:59:00 PM |
| 3954203 | 64000 | 60500 | 9/17/2018 11:54:00 AM |
| 3998909 | 19000 | 17000 | 9/10/2018 4:35:00 PM |
| 3998909 | 17000 | 15500 | 9/16/2018 5:09:00 AM |
| 4085861 | 67000 | 62500 | 9/11/2018 8:51:00 AM |
| 4085861 | 62500 | 58000 | 9/17/2018 3:35:00 AM |

Sale (sample):

| product_id | quantity_ordered | ordered_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 64 | 1 | 9/09/2018 4:37:00 PM |
| 64 | 6 | 9/11/2018 10:59:00 PM |
| 3954203 | 6 | 9/10/2018 11:54:00 AM |
| 3954203 | 1 | 9/12/2018 4:35:00 PM |
| 3954203 | 1 | 9/18/2018 5:09:00 AM |
| 4085861 | 2 | 9/10/2018 8:51:00 AM |
| 4085861 | 1 | 9/19/2018 3:35:00 AM |

Calculcate the total revenue of each product and revenue at each price

Comment: Please at least show what you have tried.

Comment: Please specify if this is MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8, as the latter has functionality not present in the former.

Comment: Are you sure All of the dates are in the correct order? One appears to go from 17th to 11th (backwards in time)

My mistake, i mistook those 2 days for each other.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem or code the solution for you. 
Beginners are welcome, but we expect ___some effort from you___ to solve your own problem before asking a question. So show us your best effort. 
___SO is not a free coding service___, although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Comment: Please read ; [How do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use two subqueries to determine the price at a specific date

the following takes the last new_price if it finds a row before the sales day else takes the old_price from next available day.

The second subselect would be not necessary, if you had for every produce one initial row, before all sales days where you have the same old_price and new_price.

the product table will profit from a combined INDEX on prodict_id and updated_at

```
SELECT
  s.`product_id`
  , s.`quantity_ordered`
  ,IFNULL(
  (SELECT `new_price` FROM product p WHERE p.`product_id` = s.`product_id`
  AND  s.`ordered_at`>= p.`updated_at` ORDER BY `updated_at` DESC LIMIT 1)
  ,(SELECT `old_price` FROM product p WHERE p.`product_id` = s.`product_id`
  AND  s.`ordered_at`< p.`updated_at` ORDER BY `updated_at` ASC LIMIT 1))
  p_price
  , s.`ordered_at`
FROM sale s
```

| product_id | quantity_ordered | p_price | ordered_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 64 | 1 | 270000 | 2018-09-09 18:37:00 |
| 64 | 6 | 239000 | 2018-09-12 00:59:00 |
| 3954203 | 6 | 60000 | 2018-09-10 13:54:00 |
| 3954203 | 1 | 64000 | 2018-09-12 18:35:00 |
| 3954203 | 1 | 60500 | 2018-09-18 07:09:00 |
| 4085861 | 2 | 67000 | 2018-09-10 10:51:00 |
| 4085861 | 1 | 58000 | 2018-09-19 05:35:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/w2OFygM1)

Comment: In my experience, it's usually far more efficient to start with the prices and find the sales, than to find the price with LIMIT 1, for each individual sale. I'll add that as answer when (if) the op makes an effort in their question.

Comment: i doubt that it will make a difference, as you make usually  a time limit and so take only s a few sales into account, the product price table, could be huge, as all products are listed with all price changes

Comment: Any sales system that has more products than sales has a big issue ;) The example may be that way, but the reality is normally that each price row will match to many Many sales. So, going that way will allow a relatively smaller number of range seeks. I've refractored client code for this many time, often yielding 10x or better lower cost.

Comment: that is speculation, that price will not change often or daily or hourly or even by the minute, but i get your point